# Regarding lambdas in python

Tags: python, lambda

I am weak in python especially

I have a class defined as the following:-

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, age):
       self.age = age
       self.id = id
```

I have a lambda to read:-

```
expr = (0, lambda acc, e: max(acc, e.age), lambda x: x)
```

From what i gather its some sort of accumulator that takes the max over the age element in the e.age key.

So my first guess was pass a list of employees into the expr:-

```
employeeList = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    employeeList.append(Employee(i, 20))

maxAge = expr(employeeList)
```

But it gives the following error:-

```
    TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me out in reading this lambda and in particular what exactly to pass to this expr? Since lambdas are not debuggable in python, this is hard.

Comment: So, you don't have a requirement, but you see a function. You don't know what that does, but you want to use it?

Comment: `expr` is a tuple of a zero and two lambdas.  what are you asking? the `expr[1]` takes two variables (`acc` and `e`). `expr[2]` takes `x`.

Comment: @thefourtheye. Yes i kind of have to. @  Wally Beaver, oh my bad i added the [] by accident i will fix that.

Comment: ``expr`` looks like a list of arguments to be passed to some map/reduce (fold) type of function, which is not present in your question. Namely, ``0`` is the initializer, the first lambda is the reduction predicate, and the second lambda is the map predicate.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal: That doesn't change anything.  it's still a tuple.  `(0, <function <lambda> at 0x101eacc08>, <function <lambda> at 0x101eacc80>)`.  For what to pass *each* lambda, see my above comment.

Comment: `404: This is not the code you are looking for`.  Are you sure your `expr` above is the same as in your debugger?  Your `TypeError` tells me it's not.

Comment: @WallyBeaver, i just put one of the lambdas in my debugger at first. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment, that's how you can complete your code using standard Python functions:

```
from functools import reduce

# your code

maxAge = reduce(expr[1], map(expr[2], employeeList), expr[0])
```

or even

```
def map_reduce(iterable, initializer, reduce_pred, map_pred):
    return reduce(reduce_pred, map(map_pred, iterable), initializer)

maxAge = map_reduce(employeeList, *expr)
```

Here, `expr[0]` is the initializer, `expr[1]` is the reduction predicate, and `expr[2]` is the map predicate.

Comment: I agree... this is very likely to be the case.  Nice.

Comment: I get what expr[0] and expr[1] are (initial values and the max function over age of employee as key). But what does expr[2] mean in my particular case? Its mapping to identity? If so then the map predicate is useless in this lambda correct?

Comment: In your particular code it just seems to be a placeholder. If you only have a map/reduce function similar to the one I wrote, but you do not need the map functionality, you pass an identity function as the map predicate. Sorry, I cannot deduce more from the information you provided.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as: `reduce(expr[1], employeeList)`

Comment: @fjarri. Thanks man. Sorry but I am extremely weak in lambdas. This was a part of a doctest so even I dont have any more information. But I knew the goal(getting the max age of the employees) and that is accomplished.